# Generating all combinations of rows of matrices (brute force) in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I have a list of matrices (with the same number of columns), say `lst_Mat` and I'd like to have all row-wise combinations of matrices in this list. For example, `lst_Mat` could be like this:

```
> lst_Mat
 [[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    1    3    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    4    2
 [4,]    2    1    3    4
 [5,]    2    3    1    4
 [6,]    2    3    4    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    2    4
[2,]    3    1    2    4
[3,]    3    2    1    4
[4,]    3    2    4    1

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    1    2    4    3
 [3,]    1    3    2    4
 [4,]    1    3    4    2
 [5,]    1    4    2    3
 [6,]    1    4    3    2
 [7,]    2    1    3    4
 [8,]    2    1    4    3
 [9,]    2    3    1    4
[10,]    3    1    2    4

[[4]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2    1    4    3
 [2,]    2    3    1    4
 [3,]    3    1    2    4
 [4,]    3    1    4    2
 [5,]    3    2    1    4
```

As such, the total number of combinations would be `6*4*10*5=1200`. This problem is analogous to the problem of generating all possible strings of English letters (i.e. a, b, c,..., x, y, z) with a specific length. For instance: `aaa, aab, aac,..., aaz, aba, abb,..., abz, aca,...` and so on.

I have come up with the following solution:

```
lst_Mat_len=list()
C=ncol(lst_Mat[[1]])
for (i in 1:length(lst_Mat))
    lst_Mat_len[[length(lst_Mat_len)+1]]=(1:nrow(lst_Mat[[i]]))

combs=do.call(expand.grid, lst_Mat_len)

for (i in 1:nrow(combs)){
    M=matrix(0, 0, C)
    for (j in 1:ncol(combs))
        M=rbind(M, lst_Mat[[j]][combs[i,j],])

    # print(M)
}
```

Sample output of `M`:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    3    2    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    1    4    3

> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    3    2    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    3    1    4
```

That is, one row per matrix, each time.
I'd appreciate any other algorithms for doing so.

Comment: Do you want to have pair-wise combinations over all the matrices?

Comment: Not pair-wise. As I said, all different combinations of rows in all matrices. One row per matrix, each time.

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) since you seem to be seeking alternative algorithms?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks @gnat -- I guess I should be more explicit in my suggestion. When I say "better suited" I imply, close on SO, and open/migrate to one of the other sites.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns not solely for alternative algorithms.

Comment: @gnat thanks for your notice but I do not that by default:-)

Comment: This just looks like a run of the mill troubleshooting problem.  Debug it.  Use [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to guide you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, I changed a little bit the example to make it more reproducible:

```
ones <- t(rep(1, 4))
lst_Mat <- list(1:6 %*% ones, 7:11 %*% ones, 12:21 %*% ones, 22:26 %*% ones)

combs <- expand.grid( sapply(lst_Mat, function(x) 1:nrow(x)) )
nbcombs <- nrow(combs)

res <- NULL
for (i in 1:nbcombs)
   res[[i]] <- t(mapply(function(mat,line) mat[line,], lst_Mat, combs[i, ]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Well, the algorithm is (more or less) the same and the way of computation is changed here. Although I see it a good solution, I'm more interested to see proposing different ALGORITHMS.

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it now!